# How to close the navigation when clicked on linked

Tags: html, css, sass

This is the code for my navbar which is in burger navbar when i'm clicking on the navbar the navbar is working fine and when i'm clicking on the link the page is going on that link but the navbar is still showing.

```
    <div class="navigation">
  <input type="checkbox" class="navigation__checkbox" id="navi-toggle" />
  <label for="navi-toggle" class="navigation__button">
      <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
  </label>

  <div class="navigation__background">&nbsp;</div>

  <nav class="navigation__nav">
      <ul class="navigation__list">
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#designs" class="navigation__link">01 Our Designs</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#services" class="navigation__link">02 Services</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#accesories" class="navigation__link">03 Accesories</a></li> 
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#carcass" class="navigation__link">04 Carcass</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#shutters" class="navigation__link">05 Shutters</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#hardware" class="navigation__link">06 Hardware</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#about" class="navigation__link">07 About us</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#location" class="navigation__link">08 Location</a></li>
          <li class="navigation__item"><a href="#contact" class="navigation__link">09 Contact Us</a></li>
          
      </ul>
  </nav>
```

And this is my sass code

```
.navigation {
&__checkbox {
    display: none;
}

&__button {
    background-color: $white;
    height: 7rem;
    width: 7rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 6rem; 
    right: 6rem; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 4;
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba($color-black, .1);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;

    }

}

&__background {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 6.5rem;
    right: 6.5rem;
    background-image: radial-gradient($primary-color, $secondary-color);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all .9s;

    



    

    // transform: scale(50);

}

&__link {
    &:link,
    &:visited {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 3rem;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: $white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        background-image: linear-gradient(99deg, transparent 0%, transparent 50%, $white 50%);
        background-size: 220%;
        transition: all .4s;
    }

    // &:hover,
    // &:active {
    //  background-position: 100%;
    //  color: $primary-color;
    //  transform: translateX(1rem);
    // }

    &:hover {
        background-position: 100%;
        color: $primary-color;
        transform: translateX(1rem);
    }
    
}



&__nav {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -3; // 3

    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    transition: all .9s;
}

&__list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

&__item {
    margin: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;

}

&__checkbox:checked ~ &__background {
    transform: scale(80);
}

&__checkbox:checked ~ &__nav {
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3;
}

&__link:hover ~ &__nav {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -3;
}

// Icon

&__icon {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    &,
    &::before,
    &::after {
        width: 3rem;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
        display:inline-block;           
    }

    
    &::before,
    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;            
        transition: all .2s;
    }

    &::before {top: -.8rem;}
    &::after {top: .8rem;}

}

&__button:hover  &__icon:before {top:-1rem;}
&__button:hover  &__icon:after {top:1rem;}

&__checkbox:checked + &__button &__icon {
    background-color: transparent;
}

&__checkbox:checked + &__button &__icon::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

&__checkbox:checked + &__button &__icon::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

}

And I'm Trying this code to work but still not working
I want in my code that when i click on the link i.e going to active the link class then the navbar will automatically open using the sass/css or javascript

```
    &__link:active ~ &__nav {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let link = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation__link');


Array.prototype.forEach.call(link, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
       let checkbox = document.querySelector('.navigation__checkbox');
       checkbox.checked = false
```

});
});